Is this example from cambridge dictionary wrong or written poorly?
The webpage https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position says the following.."Where there is more than one verb, mid position means after the first auxiliary verb or after a modal verb".
Skip forward to the examples section: Position: They sometimes go in mid position if the adverb is not the most important part of the clause or if the object is very long. Example: "She quickly ate her dinner and ran out." — here we have two verbs "ate" and "ran", yet the adverb "quickly" is before all the verbs: hasn't this example just gone against what the webpage said earlier?
thanks

"Where there is more than one verb, mid position means after the first auxiliary verb or after a modal verb".  You're totally ignoring that note. Where is the auxiliary verb or modal verb in "She quickly ate her dinner and ran out" ?

@TimR I was thinking it meant inlcuding the lesser known types of verbs — auxiliary and modal (in addition to full verbs). You can disagree with my thought process but it came across as slighlty rude by labelling it 'willful misunderstanding'.

There’re no mistakes.

She quickly ate her dinner and ran out.

The verbs in more than one verb are not referring to the ate and ran.  They refer to, for example, had eaten and would eat in
cases where lexical verbs are preceded by an auxiliary verb or a modal verb.
In such cases, the adverb follows  the first verb:
had (quickly) eaten
would (quickly) eat
Where there are two auxiliary verbs preceding the lexical verb, the adverb follows the first one:
had (quickly) been eaten

thx, so you are saying that Cambridge dictionarys clarification  (poorly imo) actually means — "Where there is more than one verb (auxiliary or modal, not lexical/full)"

It refers to various combinations including  modal and/or aux, and lexical verbs.

I read your answer again — you are saying two verbs IN A ROW, correct? I have to admit I thought it meant two verbs in the SAME CLAUSE. I could be mistaken but the website doesn't seem to clarify which of these two possibilities is the situation

From the mention of auxiliary verb and modal verb in Where there is more than one verb ..., we can tell that the dictionary is talking about combinations of these verbs with the lexical ones, not standalone lexical verbs.
